# jQuery Mobile slide transition goes in 2 parts

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, transition, slide

I'm using a jQuery mobile slide transition, but it's kind of buggy. While sliding, a small amount of pixels slides in delayed, which looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the bottom part of the new page is like 50px behind.

**This only appears on my iPhone, it runs correctly in Chrome and Firefox on my Computer.**

Does anyone know this bug and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the bottom part a fixed footer?

Comment: Nope, we are not using the footer at all

Comment: probably the second page content is shorter than the first page content. You can size the content to the device, see http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/06/content-div-height-fill-page-height/.  If you don't want the height fixed, you can use the same calculation to set the min-height CSS on the content div so it always at least fills the vertical space.

Comment: Wow, yes. Apparently, that did the job. Thank you so much!